# Docker can't pull image from repository

Tags: windows, git, docker, dockerfile

I have trouble with docker.
Im trying to create a new instance of rethinkdb on docker. I used the origin command from [dockerfile github](https://github.com/dockerfile/rethinkdb).

```
$ docker run -d -p 8080:8080 -p 28015:28015 -p 29015:29015 dockerfile/rethinkdb
```

But it returned error about image not found from the repository.
Any advice for this issue?
Thank everyone

OS version: Windows 10

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sC2Jj.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

That github repo doesn't appear to have been updated in a few years, and all the docker hub links are old. Consider using the official repo on [docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/rethinkdb/):

```
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 -p 28015:28015 -p 29015:29015 rethinkdb
```